# How do I change the font in an Evernote note to a custom size?

Tags: fonts, evernote

I'm using Evernote on Windows 7. I'm trying to change the size of text in a note, but I can only seem to select from the default fonts. Even though the program uses a text input to select font size, it doesn't seem to allow for typing custom font sizes.

**Is there any way to change this behaviour and use custom font sizes in Evernote?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Using the keyboard shortcuts to increase/decrease the font size also works.

The shortcuts have changed over time. From [this site](https://www.maketecheasier.com/premium/cheatsheet/evernote-keyboard-shortcuts/) the new ones are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>.

These work on both Windows and OS X.

Notes:

- Works on the current selection, *increasing/decreasing* different current sizes appropriately;
- Only works at insertion point for a +1/-1 (the *last* shortcut entered) size change;
- Doesn't work on the last newline character of note (if any). Just delete it and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to fix.

---

2) The Format > Font… menu shortcuts are:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or
<kbd>Right Click</kbd>,<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+(<kbd>O</kbd>;<kbd>F</kbd>) or <kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>O</kbd>,<kbd>F</kbd> followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd> <size> <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

These are the ones for Windows. (OS X to come)

Notes:

- Works on the current selection, *resetting* different current sizes;
- Works at the insertion point for ***any*** size change;
- Doesn't work on the last newline character of note (if any). Just delete it and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to fix.

**Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any way to set the new note default size* to a non-standard one.**

<sub>* Tools > Options > Note or <kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>T</kbd>,<kbd>O</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>,<kbd>Right</kbd>,<kbd>Right</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd> <type size> <kbd>Enter</kbd></sub>

<sub>**Caveats:** Tested on Evernote 5.8.4.6870 (274870) Public on Windows</sub>

Comment: This would not allow decimal font sizes.

Comment: @varfirstName As would not every other way to change font sizes in Evernote. Unless you tested on a later version/different OS than I did? Can you confirm this? Please post version/OS tested on.

Answer (score 3):

1. Select Text
2. Go to Format
3. Go to Fonts (or Show Fonts on OS X)
4. Input the desired font size
5. Hit enter!